# Stop vscode preview from scrolling

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to stop vscode preview from scrolling, while editing in another tab?

I have a preview open in a splitview, and when I scroll in the document the preview is also scrolling.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can for markdown. With other languages it would be dependent upon the extension support for that given language.

Markdown you can modify the following settings to make each interdependent of each other:

[image]

JSON of each would be:

```
"markdown.preview.scrollEditorWithPreview": true/false
"markdown.preview.scrollPreviewWithEditor": true/false
```

Comment: Looks like when I type in the editor, the preview pane scrolls even with both settings to false (trying to put the line I'm currently editing at the top of the preview).

I also tried setting `"markdown.preview.markEditorSelection": false` but this still happens.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi! Is possible to configure that behaviour on a file basis not the entire project?
aka: all .md files scrolls, but this particular file don't

Comment: @NathanDortman you should check, if you have the "Markdown All in One" extension installed. This one overwrote the setting on my machine.

Comment: @RufusBuschart yeah, I do ... do you have any recommended alternatives?

Comment: @NathanDortman I decided to use the out-of-the box functions of VS code enhanced with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.github-markdown-preview